# What should be the php/MySql query for sending and receiving data from the following database design

Tags: php, mysql, database

this is my database design for a ques n ans page.
A user can ask as many questions, receive as many answers to a single question.
ie. one question and many answers.

All i want to know is *mysql query* that'll be required for fetching the answers for a particular database. Also the *php code* that'll be involved in sending and thereby retrieving the results.

db design:

```
create table user (
 name varchar(14) not null.
 id int(11) auto_increment;

CREATE TABLE questions (
 question_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 user_id int(11) references user(id),
title varchar(255),
content text, 
PRIMARY KEY (question_id);

CREATE TABLE answers (
answer_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
question_id int(11) REFERENCES questions(question_id),
content text,
PRIMARY KEY (answer_id);
```

Comment: homework? read up on SELECT syntax and JOINing. what have you tried so far? what worked, what didn't?

Comment: What do you mean by "fetching the answers for a particular database"? Is that for one user? For one question? For all questions that have been asked?

Comment: @octern :sorry, not 'for' but 'from'. I want all the answers for a particular question. any help?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen : i know the select and join syntax. but i want to implement it through a web page, n im stuck wth the server end coding ie php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the ID for the particular question, then all you need to do is select all the records in `answers` with that question_id. If you're selecting based on some other attribute of the question, then you'd select that question from `questions` with `LEFT JOIN answers on questions.question_id = answers.question_id` in order to get all the relevant answers.

As for PHP code, read up on mysqli or PDO. This should be a textbook case of running a query and then fetching the results. Check out [example 1 on this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for how to create a DB connection and [example 1 on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) for a very simple query example. But note that if you're searching on a user-provided string, a simple query like that creates huge security holes! You should use the prepare() function instead.